# How to get load averages and compulsory memory from a script?

Tags: memory, top, load

`uptime` piped to `sed` fixes the first part but what about memory usage? `top` runs, at least by default, interactively.

So: I need to watch used RAM excluding opportunistic caching(which gets dropped as soon as the memory is needed). And ask about both because I expect a single standard tool can do it, instead of two. Or - even better - something in `/proc` indicating the RAM part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `free` tool or `cat /proc/meminfo` - they would give you memory state at this very moment.

Answer (score 1):

What you can use is `vmstat`. This tool will give you the CPU usage and memory consumption. Be aware the first row is average usage from the moment machine start so you should search for next lines.

Comment: +1 Ended up using `free` but thank You for teaching me this standard utility. Also Your post answers the question body better but ... life.

Comment: @Vorac, you ask for one utility to check CPU and memory. But it is your decision...

Comment: Indeed Your answer is the best. Accepted the other only because SE 'accept' means 'how was the problem solved'. Upvotes will take care of any confusion :)